# Install App in VERYSILENT mode with command line which written with inno setup script

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

How Should i modify my code so i can let user detemine the path of  second directory (path of java in script)

I used this Command befor i try in mode:

```
mysetup.exe /DIR="C:\test"
```

[installation path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7w5.png)
[second path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhbul.png)
And how to let user to choose one of these Component1 or component2 or both.
[choose component to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn8cZ.png)

```
#define AppName "My App"
[Setup]
AppName={#AppName}
AppVersion=1
DefaultDirName={code:getInstallDir}\{#AppName}
;DefaultDirName={pf}\My App
DisableDirPage=yes

[Files]

[Code]

#include 'System.iss'
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;
  UsagePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

function InputDirPageNextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  { Use the first path as the "destination path" }
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := Page.Values[0];
  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome,
    'Destination', '',
    'Where should App be installed?',
    False, 'New Folder');

  Page.Add('App path');
  Page.Values[0] := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
 
  UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
    'Installation', 'choose component',
    'please choose one!:',
    False, False);
  UsagePage.Add('Component1');
  UsagePage.Add('Component2');

  Page.OnNextButtonClick := @InputDirPageNextButtonClick;
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Java path', '',
    'please specify Java Folder:', False, '');

  Page.Add('Java');

  Page.OnNextButtonClick := @InputDirPageNextButtonClick;
end;
```

Comment: after : Page.Add('Java'); i added this line:Page.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{param:myparam}');   and i works but hw can i master more than one parameter. In cmd: mysetup.exe /DIR="C:\test" /path="C:\newTest"

Comment: So you are asking: "How can I use a command-line parameter to populate the directory name value on my custom directory wizard page?" Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question: You are looking for a way to use a custom command-line parameter to populate the directory value on a custom directory page. Here's one way:

```
[Code]
var
  CustomPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  CustomPath: string;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  result := true;
  CustomPath := ExpandConstant('{param:CustomPath}');
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CustomPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select Custom Path',
    'What custom path do you want?',
    'Select a directory.',
    false,
    '');
  CustomPage.Add('Custom path:');
  CustomPage.Values[0] := CustomPath;
end;
```

With this in your `[Code]` section, running the setup program with a `/CustomPath="directory name"` parameter will set the value on the form to the parameter from the command line.

Comment: How can i check component1 or component2 to install with command line

Comment: You can use the `/components` command line parameter to select components from the command line. If you have further questions about it, you can start a new question.